# GWT login using Spring - URL issue

Tags: gwt, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to solve URL login issue in GWT. We are using spring security. The problem is that everything is working in development mode but in tomcat where builded as WAR it fails.

application-context-security.xml seetings:

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" login-processing-url="/login" />
```

I have my own login.html file there si HTML form element `<form action="/login">`

I have two Spring handlers which redirects to Login.html or MyApplication.html (content,services) depends on if user autheticates or not.

If I pack my application into vsp.war (localhost:8080/vsp/) and run it, it goes to Login.html, which is correct. But always if I authenticate or not it goes to localhost:8080/login with 404 status.

My final WAR structure is:

- login

  - login.nocache.js
- vsp

  - vsp.nocache.js
- Login.html
- MyApplication.html

I have two modules for login and for rest of application (services).

Example of failure authentication handler method:

```java
@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    // always send HTTP 403
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    final StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder("Login.html?");
    if(!GWT.isProdMode()) {
        URL.append("gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&");
    }
    URL.append("error=true");
    response.sendRedirect(URL.toString());

}
```

Can anybody help me where I am doing mistake? Problem is that I dont understand the URLs if there must be /Login.html or Login.html ot /login or something different.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards Lukas

Comment: Can ypu please show ,how your login servlet mapped in the web.xml ?

Comment: I have not anything in web.xml regarding login, just only for spring security:<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I have used /login fo Spring security login but also Login.gwt.xml, Login.java for GWT parts. And there was problem with correct URLs. When I change Spring security login to something different (/differentLogin) everythinkg works fine in hosted and web mode.